# Probability to win a weighted dice game

Tags: probability

You have a dice that has 70% chance of rolling a 1 and 30% chance of rolling a 2. You win if you roll two 1's and lose if you roll two 2's (doesn't have to be consecutive). What is the chance of winning?

I know there are 3 winning combinations (1 1, 1 2 1 and 2 1 1) out of 6. The other 3 losing combinations being (2 2, 2 1 2 and 1 2 2).

But I'm not sure how to account for the 70% chance of getting 1 and 30% chance of getting 2. Would appreciate some help, thank you!

Comment: The rolls are independent; you multiply the probabilities.

Comment: Note that the problem is equivalent to: roll three such dice, and win if at least two of them are 1/lose if at least two of them are 2. (If the first two rolls match, the third roll might as well not have happened.) Do you know a formula for this situation?

Comment: I see. I think the answer is 49% (1 1) + 15% (1 2 1) and 15% (2 1 1) = 78%? Not sure what the formula is - could you tell me?

Comment: it is: $P(11)+P(121)+P(211)=0.7\cdot 0.7+0.7\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.7+0.3\cdot 0.7\cdot 0.7=0.784$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use conditional probabilities (depending on the first result):

If the first roll is a $1$, the next two rolls must not be two $2$'s, and if the first roll is a $2$, the next two rolls must be two $1$'s, so the probability to win is:
$$p = 0.7\cdot(1-0.3^2) + 0.3\cdot0.7^2 = 0.7\cdot0.91+0.3 \cdot0.49 = 0.784$$